# Why did SCS change branch template $name item paths to start with "_" instead of "#"?

Tags: sitecore-cli, scs

I recently updated Sitecore CLI version 4.2.1 to 5.2.113.

I ran `dotnet sitecore ser validate --fix` and I noticed many of these log entries:

```
[/sitecore/templates/Branches/Project/ACME CO] INCORRECT FILE PATH: ~/Pages/General Content Page/$name, 
[/sitecore/templates/Branches/Project/ACME CO] found:    ~\ACME CO\Pages\General Content Page\_name.yml,      
[/sitecore/templates/Branches/Project/ACME CO] expected: ~\ACME CO\Pages\General Content Page\#name.yml
[/sitecore/templates/Branches/Project/ACME] [M] ~\ACME CO\Pages\General Content Page\_name.yml -> ~\ACME CO\Pages\General Content Page\#name.yml
```

[image: scs changes in console]

Notice how the branch template `$name` item's file path changed from `_name.yml` to `#name.yml`.

Why was this change made?

None of the release notes mention it:

- [5.1.25](https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_CLI/5x/Sitecore_CLI_5125/Release_Notes)
- [5.2.109](https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_CLI/5x/Sitecore_CLI_52109/Release_Notes)
- [5.2.113](https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_CLI/5x/Sitecore_CLI_52113/Release_Notes)

Answer (score 2):

This conversion from Dollar('$') to ('#') is occuring from the below code snippet inside Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client.dll, which converts all the invalid file characters to '#' symbol.

[image]

I believe the changes were made to address and convert all the invalid characters to '#' using above code snippet.

Inside version 4.2.1 of Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client dll, invalid file characters were replaced with underscore('_') symbol.

[image]

Below is the list of characters that are considered to be avoided in filenames.

https://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/websites/writing/characters-avoid/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you for investigating. What is perplexing is that `_` is objectively safer for file names than `#`. Even the article you shared does not recommend using `#`.

Comment: ya I just checked version 4.2.1 Sitecore.DevEx.Serialization.Client dll...in that invalid file characters are replaced with underscore('-') character. Hence you are getting this warning now with the upgraded version i.e. above 5.